# TensorRT inference using OpenCV graph - api

Tags: opencv, tensorrt

### Background

Opencv introduce Compute graph, which every Opencv operation can be describe as graph op code. They took it further and, introduces the ability to use inference on DNN module as on item in the graph ( in-graph inference).

An example

https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/d7a/tutorial_gapi_anisotropic_segmentation.html

### Question

1. Is it possible to use `TensorRT` as `in-graph` inference?
2. if not, how one should implement custom operation for inference on `TensorRT`?

### sources:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/files/2020-09-04-GAPI_Overview.pdf
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Graph-AP

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/modules/gapi